# Install error message when installing on a Dell Inspiron 4100

Tags: installation, dell

I made a live install CD for ubuntu 12.04 to install on my dell inspiron 4100 everytime I get the install going it stops near the end and tell me there is an error and its going to desktop mode so I can figure it out but there is no error code or anything giving me an indication of what the issue might be please help I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem on the exact same machine and apparently, a lot of people are having it. The problem is with the installation software itself. You need to download the *[alternative installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)* for it to work.

As a side note, I had a problem with the alternative installation as well, where it would freeze whenever trying to configure network hardware. I circumvented this by pressing F6 at the beginning of setup to enter "Expert Setup" and working through each installation step *except* for network configuration. It took a little longer to install, but it worked like a charm. Hopefully, you won't have this snag like I did.